# "And" Selector in CSS With :hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to allow a object to move down if either the bar or sidebar are hovered. I am trying the following code:

```
#sidebarcategoryshow:hover#sidebar:hover #sidebarcategoryshow{
    margin-top: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
```

And basically I want #sidebarcategoryshow to move down if either one is hovered. Yet this does not seem to work, any idea? :( Currently it just is not working like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use two separate selectors:

```
#sidebarcategoryshow:hover #sidebarcategoryshow,
#sidebar:hover #sidebarcategoryshow {
    margin-top: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
```

If you are using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#), you could use the following:

```
#sidebarcategoryshow, #sidebar {
  &:hover #sidebarcategoryshow {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, THANK YOU! :D I did not know you could use a "," in CSS to have two separate rules! :D :D :D